# JavaFX login system from multiple tables

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, authentication

I got a javafx application that I just started making as I am wanting to learn java some more. I am working on a login system. The problem I have is that I want to user to login with his or her flight number and his or her last name.

The flight number is in a table called "flight" and the lastname is in a table called "passenger". I know how to make a login system where the username and password are in the same table. But I am not sure how to do this with data from two different tables.

I would love if someone could help me!

CODE:

```
package databasetesten;

import databasetesten.connection.ConnectionUtil;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author Matt Holland
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TextField textEmail;

    @FXML
    private PasswordField textPassword;

    Stage dialogStage = new Stage();
    Scene scene;

    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;

    public FXMLDocumentController() {
        connection = ConnectionUtil.connectdb();
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        String email = textEmail.getText().toString();
        String password = textPassword.getText().toString();

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE username = ? and password = ?";

        try {
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, email);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, password);
            resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            if (!resultSet.next()) {
                infoBox("Enter Correct Email and Password", "Failed", null);
            } else {
                infoBox("Login Successfull", "Success", null);
                Node source = (Node) event.getSource();
                dialogStage = (Stage) source.getScene().getWindow();
                dialogStage.close();
                scene = new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLMenuEmployee.fxml")));
                dialogStage.setScene(scene);
                dialogStage.show();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void infoBox(String infoMessage, String titleBar, String headerMessage) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.setTitle(titleBar);
        alert.setHeaderText(headerMessage);
        alert.setContentText(infoMessage);
        alert.showAndWait();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    }
}
```

This is what I have for my current login. And this works fine.

And the database looks like this.
Database name: Airport

Table: flight

```
flightnumber   IATA   Timezone
ENG456HNJ      AMS    1
```

Table: passenger

```
firstname    lastname    
Bob          Smith
```

So I guess my question is. How do I make it so that a passenger can login with his flightnumber and his or her lastname? Data from two different tables?

Comment: What is the actual logic for determining what you would consider to be a successful login?

Comment: If I am not mistaken he wants users to be able to login with flight number or last name using the same password

Comment: A successful login will be if a passenger enters his or her flightnumber in the first textbox and his or her lastname is the second textbox. So you could  say that the flightnumber is the username and the password is the lastname of the passenger

Comment: If the Flight and Passenger tables are not linked then how will you know if `Mr Smith` is on flight `ENG456HNJ` Maybe a good Database Design course would be a better first step in your learning curve!

Comment: Your database (at least as far as you describe it) simply doesn't contain the information you are looking for; there is no data in there describing which flight numbers belong to which passengers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting data from two tables is not so good idea in your case. In your example you have already implemented it with email and password. With flights you should just change email to flight number and password to last name accordingly.

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM `FLIGHTS` WHERE `flightNumber` = ? and `lastName` = ?";
```

After you get data from the data you just need to show to your user.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will change my database layout so everything is in 1 table! Thanks again!

Comment: @Snidjers you are qelcome